# system ID(system identification number) for CDMA network in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to find [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_identification_number) (System Identification Number) for CDMA network in iPhone. I can't seem to get it from CTCarrier class. Is there there an alternative way to find it. If you have any idea please let me know?